# Why does slapd say "bdb_equality_candidates: (objectClass) not indexed" when the indices actually exist?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openldap, slapd

I have slapd `2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3` installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and running as master to a secondary sync.  It works well for all things LDAP, but I notice these errors in `/var/log/debug` every so often:

```
May 19 09:19:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (objectClass) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (objectClass) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (objectClass) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (objectClass) not indexed
May 19 09:20:01 ldap1 slapd[9507]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
```

Don't these indices already exist (created via https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup )? I can see them when I run `slapcat -n 0`. Do I need to create them for both master and slave? (the entry `olcDatabase={2}` and `/var/lib/ldap/accesslog` seem to indicate they only exist for the slave setup)

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
...
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
...
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=xxxxxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xxx
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
olcDbIndex: memberUid eq
olcDbIndex: uniqueMember eq
olcDbIndex: cn pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: sn pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: uid pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: displayName pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: default sub
olcDbIndex: uidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: gidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: mail,givenName eq,subinitial
olcDbIndex: dc eq
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
```